# How to log/debug object properties, ignoreing method/function clutter

Tags: javascript, debugging, properties, console

I'd like to use Chrome's dev console to track an object's properties, but on objects with a lot of methods, it's a pain to wade through all the function references. Is there a pretty way to debug objects *without displaying their associated methods/functions*? I've been toying with the following code, to replicate the object and strip function references, but I can't get it working... Thanks!

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script>
function plog(obj){
    var key;
    var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
    for (key in obj){
        if(typeof(obj.key) == "function") {
            delete clone[key];
        }
    }
    console.log(clone);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="plog(window);">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value of property you should use index access like `obj[key]` inside `for-in` loop beecause `key` is a `String` with the name of property.

```
var getProperties = function(obj) {
    var propsCopy,
        i;
    propsCopy = {};
    for(i in obj) {
        if(typeof(obj[i]) !== 'function') {
            propsCopy[i] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return propsCopy;
};

var obj = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    fn: function(x) {
        return x * x;
    }
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(getProperties(obj));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/M77B3/)

Also it could be good to read this [documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties).

[image]

Comment: When running this on the "window", the function names are still being shown, although they contain null values. Is there any way to exclude those?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of console output to my answer. It works properly. What do you mean saying `on the "window"`?

Comment: I mean if you call "console.log(getProperties(window))". Literally, the window containing the current document. It has dozens of function references... Also, how did you gray the text in your last comment?

Comment: Ok I see. If you mean e.g. `onclick: null`, this is not a function yet. Because the event handler is not assigned. So it's just a property with `null` value.

Comment: Right, I don't want that to show. I want to remove the key so it is not shown at all.

Comment: So just check if it's null. `if(typeof(obj[i]) !== 'function' && obj[i] !== null) { ... }`